Prove the Alternate Segment Theorem without using Radius at Right Angle to Tangent
The Alternate Segment Theorem, or Tangent-Chord Theorem, is formulated as follows:

The angle between a tangent and a chord is equal to the angle
subtended by the same chord in the alternate segment.

Its proof of which I know is located here, and it uses the Right Angle to Tangent of Circle goes through Center, which I would like to avoid if possible.
I would also like to avoid trigonometry, triangle similarity, as well as areas. The perfect proof would be involving the Inscribed Angle Theorem and other basics.
Is there a possible proof matching my criteria?

I have the following idea of a possible candidate for a proof.
Construct a circle with center $O$. Mark a point $T$ on that circle and draw tangent $MN$ with $T$ being the tangent point. Points $M$ and $N$ should be chosen in such way that $T$ lies between $M$ and $N$. Choose an arbitrary point $P \not\equiv T$ on that same circle. Then we can assume without loss of generality that angle $\alpha = \angle PTN$ is an acute angle between tangent $MN$ and chord $PT$.

Construct a line parallel to $MN$ through point $P$. Since $P$ is a point on a circle not coincident with $P$, there are two possible cases:

The constructed line is a tangent through point $P$.
The constructed line is a secant through point $P$.

Let's examine the latter case. Then there exists another point $Q\not\equiv P$ where this line will intersect the circle.

Then $\angle TPQ = \angle PTN = \alpha$ as alternate interior angles between $MN\parallel PQ$. By Inscribed Angle Theorem, we have $\angle TPQ = \frac{1}{2}\overset{\smile}{QT}$.
How do I proceed from here? One idea I have is to construct a ray $QT$, mark a point $K$ on that ray so that $QT < QK$, and then prove that $TN$ bisects angle $\angle PTK$. If so, it follows that triangle $TPQ$ is isosceles, and $\overset{\smile}{PT} = \overset{\smile}{QT}$, which proves the statement.



In the fig., let
$\angle CBH = \angle 1$
$\angle DBC = \angle 2$
$\angle BDC = \angle 3$
$\angle BEC = \angle 4$
$\angle GBC = \angle 5$
$\angle BFC = \angle 6$
Now, $\angle 1 + \angle 2 = 90^0$
Also, $\angle 2 + \angle 3 = 90^0$
$\implies \angle 1 = \angle 3$
also, $\angle 3 = \angle 4$
$\implies \angle 1 = \angle 4$
Now, $\angle 1 + \angle 5 = 180^0$
Also, $PATB$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.
$\implies \angle 4 + \angle ^ = 180^0$
$\implies \angle 5 = \angle 6$
QED

There is no point $M$ in your diagram, so I have no idea what is angle $\angle BAM$.

@Rusurano Notation mistake, I have corrected it

Consider a point $B'$ on the circle near to $B$, and another chord $AD$ as in figure below. By the inscribed angle theorem we have:
$$
\angle B'AD=\angle DBF.
$$
In the limit $B'\to B$ line $BF$ becomes tangent at $B$ and by the above equality the angle $\angle DBF$ formed by this tangent with $BD$ is equal to angle $\angle BAD$, as we wanted to prove.


Are limits even defined in Euclidean geometry? The approach is interesting for sure, though.

@Rusurano They were widely used in geometry from XVII to early XX century.
